# Add subtitles to video using ffmpeg

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, mingw

ffmpeg is asking to compile with minGW to add subtitles to video. I have installed MinGW. I am following this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo to add subtitles. This filter requires ffmpeg to be compiled with --enable-libass. how can i compile those filters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile `libass` (the library) so that ffmpeg can link against it.  https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers is one way (cross compiles with it). GL!

Comment: I have done.  download repository: 
   zip file: https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/archive/master.zip and unzip
   or clone the repository: c:\> git clone https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers.git
 Next run one of the "native_build/build_locally_XXX.bat" file.  How do I enable libass using command line?

Comment: it will be built and included for you. Or just use the zeranoe ffmpeg builds they have libass included.